# Android: Creating a notification beacon in action bar that can be updated dynamically

Tags: android, notifications, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Maybe im just not searching the right keywords, but im trying to replace the home icon w. a notifications beacon that by default is grey , but turns red and displays a number inside the icon that represents how many new notifications a user has similar to the ones found in most of the major social networking apps ( facebook, g+ , foursquare ect..)

If asking for a snippet is to much can someone at least roughly outline how i would go about creating such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this. You just have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033367/custom-notification-view`.This might help.