# Actionbar notification count icon (badge) like Google has

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is there a android standard badge or method to show action bar notification icon with a count like on Google examples?

[image: count 3 on picture]

If not, then what is the best way to make it?
I'm new to android, please help.

Comment: I've updated my answer to link to a complete notification icon implementation.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best solution or not, but it is what I need.

Please tell me if you know what is need to be changed for better performance or quality. In my case, I have a button.

Custom item on my menu - main.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/feed_update_count"
    android:icon="@drawable/shape_notification"
    android:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

Custom shape drawable (background square) - shape_notification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="#22000000" android:width="2dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#CC0001"/>
</shape>
```

Layout for my view - feed_update_count.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/notif_count"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minWidth="32dp"
     android:minHeight="32dp"
     android:background="@drawable/shape_notification"
     android:text="0"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:padding="2dp"
     android:singleLine="true">    
</Button>
```

MainActivity - setting and updating my view

```
static Button notifCount;
static int mNotifCount = 0;    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    View count = menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();
    notifCount = (Button) count.findViewById(R.id.notif_count);
    notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setNotifCount(int count){
    mNotifCount = count;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: It's great ! But if you use AppCompat, you should set the ActionLayout in code : `MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.badge);
  MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.feed_update_count);
  notifCount = (Button) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);`

Comment: supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() need to use instead of invalidateOptionsMenu() if you target for API level below 11

Comment: +1 Helped a lot! However: You don't need the `android:icon="..."` in the menu item XML. The `android:actionLayout="..."` is enough, there. For the `Button` in the layout XML, you _can_ use the self-closing tag `<Button ... />` because the tag cannot have content. You need to close the `<shape>` tag (again: self-closing). And you don't need the `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. For me, that does not even work, as the badge is always inflated from XML again. So, the whole `setNotifCount(...)` is useless. Just call `setText(...)` on the badge. And you can cast `getActionView()` to `Button` directly.

Comment: Also, if you use AppCompat, you should change badge xml menu <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/feed_update_count"
        android:icon="@drawable/shape_notification"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always" />
</item>
</menu>

Comment: How to you handle onClick events? OnOptionsItemSelected and onClickListener unfortunately don't work for me.

Comment: @Webster notifCount.setOnClickListener(...); that's all inside

Comment: The above answer doesn't work with onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: @AndrewS Please check my answer for better approach. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47362866/4647628

Comment: Don't forget, you also need to handle an onClickListener for the text view, as it consumes onClick/onTouch Events.

Answer (score 134):

**Edit** Since version 26 of the support library (or androidx) you no longer need to implement a custom `OnLongClickListener` to display the tooltip. Simply call this:

```
TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(menu_hotlist, getString(R.string.hint_show_hot_message));
```

---

I'll just share my code in case someone wants something like this:
[image]

- **layout/menu/menu_actionbar.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      ...
      <item android:id="@+id/menu_hotlist"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_notifitcation_icon"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_bell"
          android:title="@string/hotlist" />
      ...
  </menu>
  ```
- **layout/action_bar_notifitcation_icon.xml**

  Note **style** and **android:clickable** properties. these make the layout the size of a button and make the background gray when touched.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:clickable="true"
      style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/hotlist_bell"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_bell"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"
          android:contentDescription="bell"
          />

      <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/hotlist_hot"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:minWidth="17sp"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textColor="#ffffffff"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="@null"
          android:layout_alignTop="@id/hotlist_bell"
          android:layout_alignRight="@id/hotlist_bell"
          android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
          android:paddingBottom="1dp"
          android:paddingRight="4dp"
          android:paddingLeft="4dp"
          android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- **drawable-xhdpi/ic_bell.png**

  A 64x64 pixel image with 10 pixel wide paddings from all sides. You are supposed to have 8 pixel wide paddings, but I find most default items being slightly smaller than that. Of course, you'll want to use different sizes for different densities.
- **drawable/rounded_square.xml**

  Here, #ff222222 (color #222222 with alpha #ff (fully visible)) is the background color of my Action Bar.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <shape
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="2dp" />
      <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
      <stroke android:color="#ff222222" android:width="2dp"/>
  </shape>
  ```
- **com/ubergeek42/WeechatAndroid/WeechatActivity.java**

  Here we make it clickable and updatable! I created an abstract listener that provides Toast creation on onLongClick, the code was taken from from [the sources of ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#L249-L278).

  ```
  private int hot_number = 0;
  private TextView ui_hot = null;

  @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
      menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_actionbar, menu);
      final View menu_hotlist = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_hotlist).getActionView();
      ui_hot = (TextView) menu_hotlist.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);
      updateHotCount(hot_number);
      new MyMenuItemStuffListener(menu_hotlist, "Show hot message") {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              onHotlistSelected();
          }
      };
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  // call the updating code on the main thread,
  // so we can call this asynchronously
  public void updateHotCount(final int new_hot_number) {
      hot_number = new_hot_number;
      if (ui_hot == null) return;
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              if (new_hot_number == 0)
                  ui_hot.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              else {
                  ui_hot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  ui_hot.setText(Integer.toString(new_hot_number));
              }
          }
      });
  }

  static abstract class MyMenuItemStuffListener implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
      private String hint;
      private View view;

      MyMenuItemStuffListener(View view, String hint) {
          this.view = view;
          this.hint = hint;
          view.setOnClickListener(this);
          view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
      }

      @Override abstract public void onClick(View v);

      @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
          final Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
          view.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);
          view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);
          final Context context = view.getContext();
          final int width = view.getWidth();
          final int height = view.getHeight();
          final int midy = screenPos[1] + height / 2;
          final int screenWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
          Toast cheatSheet = Toast.makeText(context, hint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          if (midy < displayFrame.height()) {
              cheatSheet.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT,
                      screenWidth - screenPos[0] - width / 2, height);
          } else {
              cheatSheet.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, height);
          }
          cheatSheet.show();
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Very useful and descriptive. Thanks! That's what I really needed. Just to add some topics which might be useful. You've to put `app:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_notifitcation_icon"` instead of `android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_notifitcation_icon"` if you've to use `MenuItemCompat.getActionView` instead of `menu.findItem(R.id.menu_hotlist).getActionView();` for compatibility issues. `MenuItem.getActionView` isn't compatible with API level < 11.

Comment: **Note style and android:clickable properties. these make the layout the size of a button and make the background selected colored when touched.** Very useful!

Comment: it works like a charm. tnx bro. but in my case, i use default toolbar and i should use
"app:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_notifitcation_icon" instead
or i always get null.
tnx again

Comment: As a tip, Android has a drawable to notification. So, instead of creating a custom shape, you can set the background of the TextView to @android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay".

Comment: For Appcompat - public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_actionbar, menu);MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_hotlist);MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.action_bar_notifitcation_icon);final View menu_hotlist = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);ui_hot = (TextView) menu_hotlist.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);updateHotCount(hot_number);new MyMenuItemStuffListener(menu_hotlist, "Show hot message") {@Override public void onClick(View v) { /*dosomething*/ }};return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);}

Comment: Native: `android:actionLayout`; AppCompat: `app:actionLayout` in your menu item.

Comment: I was able to show a dot at the top using `app:actionLayout="@layout/notification_icon_layout"` but then the icon stops detecting the touch. Here is my xml https://pastebin.com/UFwNdWFr

Answer (score 64):

Just to add. If someone wants to implement a filled circle bubble, heres the code (name it `bage_circle.xml`):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:thickness="9dp"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    >

    <solid
        android:color="#F00"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#FFF" />

    <padding
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

You may have to adjust the thickness according to your need.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here's the layout for button (name it `badge_layout.xml`):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconButton
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_icon_bg"
        android:id="@+id/badge_icon_button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/badge_icon_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/badge_icon_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/badge_icon_button"
        android:text="10"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Menu create item:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_messages"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/badge_layout"/>
```

In `onCreateOptionsMenu` get reference to the Menu item:

```
    itemMessages = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_messages);

    badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemMessages.getActionView();
    itemMessagesBadgeTextView = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.badge_textView);
    itemMessagesBadgeTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // initially hidden

    iconButtonMessages = (IconButton) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.badge_icon_button);
    iconButtonMessages.setText("{fa-envelope}");
    iconButtonMessages.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar_icon_color_disabled));

    iconButtonMessages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (HJSession.getSession().getSessionId() != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getThis(), HJActivityMessagesContexts.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, HJRequestCodes.kHJRequestCodeActivityMessages.ordinal());
            } else {
                showLoginActivity();
            }
        }
    });
```

After receiving notification for messages, set the count:

```
itemMessagesBadgeTextView.setText("" + count);
itemMessagesBadgeTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
iconButtonMessages.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

This code uses [Iconify-fontawesome](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify).

```
compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.1.+'
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code for above action bar. It looks pretty good.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? Some code would be very useful

Comment: @NiteshKhatri sorry for being so late in providing the code. I thought it was easy. But you got so many upvotes for your comments meaning that other developers are finding it difficult too.

Comment: iconify is a great lib!

Comment: It is very good, however the number , text is appearing on the left side of middle of the round (radius). How to solve it

Comment: @FarruhHabibullaev make sure that you set android:gravity="center" in the textView.

Comment: Long numbers blow out of the TextView and cause the circle to be much smaller. Any idea on how to scale size as numbers grow?

Comment: textview gets in background

Comment: If we use `oval` in place of `ring` it looking good in my view.

Comment: getting null pointer at `itemMessagesBadgeTextView = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.badge_textView);`

Comment: @AshishKudale sorry, but can't help you without reading the complete code. Are you sure you implemented layout in menu and that the menu is getting generated?

Comment: Yes I have asked question on StackOverflow yesterday  
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/48963646/3154636

Answer (score 29):

I don't like `ActionView` based solutions,
my idea is:

1. create a layout with `TextView`, that `TextView` will be populated by
   application
2. when you need to draw a `MenuItem`:

   2.1. inflate layout

   2.2. call `measure()` & `layout()` (otherwise `view` will be 0px x 0px, it's too small for most use cases)

   2.3. set the `TextView`'s text

   2.4. make "screenshot" of the view

   2.6. set `MenuItem`'s icon based on bitmap created on 2.4
3. profit!

so, result should be something like
[image]

1. create layout
   here is a simple example

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/counterPanel"
>     android:layout_width="32dp"
>     android:layout_height="32dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery">
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:id="@+id/counterValuePanel"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/counterBackground"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:background="@drawable/unread_background" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/count"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="1"
>             android:textSize="8sp"
>             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>             android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

`@drawable/unread_background` is that green `TextView`'s background, 
`@drawable/ic_menu_gallery` is not really required here, it's just to preview layout's result in IDE.

2. add code into `onCreateOptionsMenu`/`onPrepareOptionsMenu`

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

       MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.testAction);
       menuItem.setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(count, R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery));

       return true;
   }
   ```
3. Implement build-the-icon method:

   ```
   private Drawable buildCounterDrawable(int count, int backgroundImageId) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter_menuitem_layout, null);
       view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

       if (count == 0) {
           View counterTextPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.counterValuePanel);
           counterTextPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       } else {
           TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
           textView.setText("" + count);
       }

       view.measure(
               View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
               View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
       view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

       view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
       view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

       return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
   }
   ```

The complete code is here: https://github.com/cvoronin/ActionBarMenuItemCounter

Comment: camelCaseCoder, when you want to change counter image's location to top right, you can, for example, add android:layout_gravity="top|right" to counterValuePanel's layout properties

Comment: It will be helpful to know why you don't prefer actionview based solutions. Is it complexity or performance?

Answer (score 26):

Ok, for **@AndrewS** solution to work with **v7 appCompat library**:

```
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:someNamespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/saved_badge"
        someNamespace:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/shape_notification" />

</menu>
```

.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.saved_badge);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.feed_update_count);
    View view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    notifCount = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.notif_count);
    notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
}

private void setNotifCount(int count){
    mNotifCount = count;
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: if you are using xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in your xml layout, use app:actionLayout="@layout/shoppingcar_icon" 
instead of android:actionLayout="@layout/shoppingcar_icon"

Comment: @OscarCalderon, it's true. Before I am getting NPE, after I changed `android:actionLayout` to `app:actionLayout` it workes like charm.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the answers to these questions, particularly the second one which has sample code:

[How to implement dynamic values on menu item in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560526/how-to-implement-dynamic-values-on-menu-item-in-android)

[How to get text on an ActionBar Icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288989/how-to-get-text-on-an-actionbar-icon/16648170)

From what I see, You'll need to create your own custom `ActionView` implementation. An alternative might be a custom `Drawable`. Note that there appears to be no native implementation of a notification count for the Action Bar.

EDIT: The answer you were looking for, with code: [Custom Notification View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033367/custom-notification-view) with [sample implementation](https://code.google.com/p/motivatormaker-android)

Comment: tnx for reply, but i don't understand how to show number, not icon like on your first link.
can you help with this?

Comment: Have you read the other links? They offer some options. Additionally you can put text in `Drawable`s as seen in the following two links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691818/combine-image-and-text-to-drawable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972445/how-to-put-text-in-a-drawable

Comment: i'm going deeper and deeper with your answers...
i have this code

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_notification" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences" />
</layer-list>

and i need to replace icon (ic_menu_preferences) with drawable which has text. how can i do this?

Comment: I don't have much experience with this, but I believe you may be able to create custom XML attributes for a `Drawable` through something like the link [here](http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/) and then make an attribute for your custom `Drawable` that has text over it so you can create the whole thing in XML and fit it as you wished. Alternatively, you could add the Drawable in Java if this is too hard.

Answer (score 3):

When you use toolbar:

```
....
private void InitToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    toolbartitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletool);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.show_post);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    Menu menu = toolbar.getMenu();
    MenuItem menu_comments = menu.findItem(R.id.action_comments);
    MenuItemCompat
            .setActionView(menu_comments, R.layout.menu_commentscount);
    View v = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu_comments);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Your Action
        }
    });
    comment_count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count);
}
```

and in your load data call refreshMenu():

```
private void refreshMenu() {
    comment_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    comment_count.setText("" + post_data.getComment_count());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a very good solution [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-badges-item-counts-in-android), I'm using it with kotlin.

First, in the drawable folder you have to create `item_count.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<solid android:color="#f20000" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#FFF" />
<padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

In your `Activity_Main` Layout some like:

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/badgeLayout"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/badge_layout1"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relative_layout1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnBadge"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@mipmap/ic_notification" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtBadge"
                        android:layout_width="18dp"
                        android:layout_height="18dp"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout1"
                        android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                        android:text="22"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="7sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:gravity="center"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

And you can modify like:

```
btnBadge.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view,"badge click", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG) .setAction("Action", null).show()
        txtBadge.text = "0"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I found better way to do it. 
if you want to use something like this

[image]

Use this dependency

```
   compile 'com.nex3z:notification-badge:0.1.0'
```

create one xml file in drawable and Save it as Badge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#66000000"/>
        <size android:width="30dp" android:height="40dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="1dp" android:right="0.6dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/Error_color"/>
        <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Now wherever you want to use that badge use following code in xml.
with the help of this you will be able to see that badge on top-right corner of your image or anything.

```
  <com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Your_ICON/IMAGE"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/Your_ICON/IMAGE"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    app:badgeBackground="@drawable/Badge"
    app:maxTextLength="2"
    ></com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge>
```

Now finally on yourFile.java use this 2 simple thing..
1) Define

```
 NotificationBadge mBadge;
```

2) where your loop or anything which is counting this number use this:

```
 mBadge.setNumber(your_LoopCount);
```

here,   `mBadge.setNumber(0)` will not show anything.

Hope this help.