# Action Bar icon margins

Tags: android, xml, notifications, icons, android-actionbar

I have developed this solution to show notifications in the actionbar. The result is that

[image]

Like can you there is no right margin in the shape and I want something like this

[image]

My code is extracted from [Actionbar notification count icon (badge) like Google has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696486/actionbar-notification-count-icon-like-google-have). And this is my code:

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/feed_update_count"
    android:icon="@layout/custom_shape_notification"
    android:showAsAction="always">
</item>
</menu>
```

custom_shape_notifications.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#22000000" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<solid android:color="#CC0001" />
```

feed_update_count.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/notif_count"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:minWidth="32dp"
          android:minHeight="32dp"
          android:background="@layout/custom_shape_notification"
          android:text="1"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:singleLine="true">    
</Button>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly wrap the button in a layout(Linear, Relative etc.) of your choice and add the layout margin to it and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your button inside relative layout using wrap_content attributes and use android:paddingRight="10dp" in your relative layout file in feed_update_count.xml.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="APPLY"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```