# Menu Item null--->NullPointerException

Tags: android, menuitem

I would put a number on the button that represent the numbers of notify like facebooks app.
I follow the first example in this topic :

[Actionbar notification count icon (badge) like Google has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696486/actionbar-notification-count-icon-like-google-have)

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.badge);

        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.feed_update_count);
        notifCount = (Button) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(SingletonGrafica.getNumeroNotifica()));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

When I call :

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.badge);
```

I obtain NullPointer Exception.Anyone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, It is a helpful practice to mark an answer as correct if you receive one. (I think you received two)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the menu first:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the navigation_menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

and if you want to update the menu you should do it in:
**onPrepareOptionsMenu**

if you want the **onPrepareOptionsMenu** function to be called again you can call             **invalidateOptionsMenu**();

Answer (score 0):

You can also add item from code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.add("Badge");MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.feed_update_count);
        return true;
    }
```