# How to inflate badge counter in MenuItem using custom LayerDrawable

Tags: android, menuitem, badge, layerdrawable

I was following [this article](http://www.jmhend.me/layerdrawable-menuitems). Unfortunatelly, badge isn't drawn. Of course I changed `invalidateOptionsMenu` method to `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` method.

I was checking the log, step by step and found out that ***`draw`* method in custom `Drawable` named `BadgeDrawable` is never called**. Why is that?

I'm trying to use it in AppCompatActivity using Support Design Library version 23.0.1

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696486/actionbar-notification-count-icon-like-google-have/26017587#26017587) answer but it seems to be out of date.

Is there anyone who managed to implement badger counter for MenuItem icon inside `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`?
If the way shown in the [article](http://www.jmhend.me/layerdrawable-menuitems) is wrong then could you suggest other way to achieve the result as in example below?:
[image]

Here is a setup inside my application:

LayerDrawable XML `ic_filter_notifications.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_filter_notification"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_filter_grey600_18dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <!-- set a place holder Drawable so android:drawable isn't null -->
    <item android:id="@+id/ic_filter_badge"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_filter_grey600_18dp">

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Menu that I use in the Toolbar `menu_activity_main.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cobytu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        cobytu:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        android:orderInCategory="1000000"
        android:title="@string/menu_logout"
        cobytu:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:title="@string/filters"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_notifications"
        cobytu:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_location"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map_marker_radius_grey600_18dp"
        android:title="@string/location"
        cobytu:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

This is function sets the count int for new BadgeDrawable inside UsefulFunctions class - `UsefulFunctions.java`:

```
 public class UsefulFunctions {

     private Context ctx;

     public UsefulFunctions(Context context){
                ctx = context;
            }


       public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon,
            int count) {

        BadgeDrawable badge;

        // Reuse drawable if possible
        Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_filter_badge);
        if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
            badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
        } else {
            Log.d("mTAG", UsefulFunctions.class.getName()
                    + " I'm creating new BadgeDrawable!");
            badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
        }

        badge.setCount(count);
        icon.mutate();
        Log.d("mTAG",
                UsefulFunctions.class.getName() + " badge: " + badge.toString()
                        + " count: " + count);
        icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_filter_badge, badge);

    }
}
```

This is the important scrap of my MainActivity where I invoke BadgeDrawable creation. I also show what's inside onCreate and in onOptionsItemSelected, may be needed - `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,  DialogFragmentFilters.FiltersRefreshInterface{

    public String username;


    //CollapsingToolbarLayout
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbarLayout;

    //Toolbar
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    //TabLayout
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private MyPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    //NavigationDraver
    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM_ID = "selected_item_id";
    private static final String FIRST_TIME = "first_time";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private int mSelectedId;
    private boolean mUserSawDrawer = false;
    private TextView mNavHeaderNameText;
    private TextView mNavHeaderEmailText;


    private  DatabaseHandler db;
    private  UserFunctions userFunctions;
    private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    private JSONObject jsonLocation = new JSONObject();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        username = db.getUserDetails().get(DatabaseHandler.getKEY_USER_LOGIN());

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        setupToolbar();
        setupTablayout();


        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View header = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header, null);
        mNavHeaderNameText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_nav_header_name);
        mNavHeaderNameText.setText("Siema "+username+"!");

        mNavHeaderEmailText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_nav_header_email);
        mNavHeaderEmailText.setText(db.getUserDetails().get(DatabaseHandler.getKEY_USER_EMAIL()));


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,mToolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        if (!didUserSeeDrawer()) {
            showDrawer();
            markDrawerSeen();
        } else {
            hideDrawer();
        }

        mSelectedId = savedInstanceState == null ? R.id.navigation_item_4 : savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM_ID);
        navigate(mSelectedId);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            showActionDialog(id);
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_logout:
            dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(
                    MainActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog));
            dialogBuilder
                    .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.logoutAlertTitle))
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logout).setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.logoutAlertMessage)).setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.logoutAlertYesButton),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                                    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_mainContent))
                                            .animate()
                                            .alpha(0f)
                                            .setListener(
                                                    new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                                        public void onAnimationEnd(
                                                                Animator animation) {
                                                            mDrawerLayout
                                                                    .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                            mDrawerLayout
                                                                    .setAlpha(1f);
                                                            mDrawerLayout
                                                                    .animate()
                                                                    .setListener(null);
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                    userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());

                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                    // MainActivity.this.deleteDatabase("cobytu_db");
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.logoutAlertNoButton),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
            alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }

            return false;
        }

    public int filterCounter = 0;

    class FetchCountTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // example count. This is where you'd 
            // query your data store for the actual count.
            return 5; 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Integer count) {
            setNotifCount(count);
        }
    }

    private void setNotifCount(int count){
        filterCounter = count;
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter);
        LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();

        // Update LayerDrawable's BadgeDrawable
        Log.d("mTag", "onCreateOptionsMenu: this: " + this.toString());
        UsefulFunctions.setBadgeCount(this, icon, filterCounter);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRefreshFilters(int counter) {
        setupTablayout();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "List has been refreshed! " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        filterCounter = counter;
        new FetchCountTask.execute();
    }



}
```

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: @pskink - I've posted what I have. Please have a look into description again.

Comment: start with the simple `Drawable` like [this](http://pastebin.com/2nqrBn0k) if it works try to change its look to match your needs

Comment: @pskink - I tried what you suggested and **still** the `draw` function is never called:

 `@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
     Log.d("mTAG", getClass().getName() + ": I'M INSIDE draw !");
        canvas.drawColor(0x5500ff00);
        String text = Integer.toString(cnt);
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, -textBounds.top / 2, paint);
    }`

Comment: try this http://pastebin.com/N0MKuEuT, tested on 4.4 with support lib

Comment: @pskink again, no result. The `draw` function inside `D` class was not touched.

Comment: what api level are you running?

Comment: I'm testing on 5.1.1 (Xperia Z3 Compact) Now trying on 4.1.2 (Samsung S III Mini) and there's also no result.

Comment: btw your `Toolbar mToolbar` is not setup

Comment: It doesn't matter, I guess.

Comment: it does, call `setSupportActionBar`

Comment: sorry, I have mToolbar setup inside `setupToolbar()` function:
`private void setupToolbar() {
  mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
  setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
  // Show menu icon
  final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
  ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }`

Comment: i think that nobody will help you if you are posting only parts of your code

Comment: I know that the problem is with `draw` function inside cutrom Drawable class. I tested my setup inside MainActivity and it works, problem is inside `BadgeDrawable` class. Please tell me which part of code would you like to see?

Comment: first check `MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter); item.setIcon(d);`

Comment: The result is that icon is not changed and in log I can see only that constructor of class `D` was called and nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94544/discussion-between-lynx-and-pskink).

Comment: see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfuvdvcepfbkjoz/src.zip?dl=0) for a working sources

Comment: and? did you try them?

Comment: Yes, your code works as we all want. Now I'm looking into my code to examine what's wrong. It's all the same by my code is not working...

Comment: see again [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfuvdvcepfbkjoz/src.zip?dl=0) for a more realistic solution, notice how menu.xml looks like now

Comment: maybe it sounds strange, but it seems that .setIcon function brings no result for me. Maybe I should use DrawableCompat instead Drawable?

Comment: so how come `setIcon` works for me? see `setupBadge` method

Comment: just get my sources and forget about that artificial `layer-list` drawables created for each badge

Comment: It's also strange for me. 
Is `setupBadge` meant to be inside MainActivity from new code that you posted? If so, there's old MainActivity there.

Comment: If you have TeamViewer, maybe it's a good idea to take a glance on my code...

Comment: old? what do you mean? my MainActivity.java is `3360` bytes long and created `2015-11-09 11:26`, path: `src/main/java/org/pskink/badge/MainActivity.java`, md5sum: `87f3c0ee532d7da52f5c30cab5d4c432`, no TeamViewer

Comment: I configured it in the way you presented inside my project and it doesn't work. I have Navigation drawer, TabLayout, AppBarLayout, PagerAdapter,  and CoordinatorLayout inside my MainActivity .xml. Maybe this causes some troubles.

Comment: so try adding your components to my sources one by one

Comment: also what happens if you call `item.setIcon(res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_....))` ?

Comment: `item.setIcon(res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_....))` gives no result

Comment: `Log.d` the value of `menu.getClass()` and `item.getClass()` what do you see?

Comment: `Log.d("mTAG", getClass().getName() + " onCreateOptionsMenu: menu.getClass(): " + menu.getClass() + "; item.getClass(): " + item.getClass());`
 gives
`com.lynx.home.MainActivity onCreateOptionsMenu: menu.getClass(): class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder; item.getClass(): class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl`

Comment: ok i have the same classes, if `setIcon` does not work, did you try: `setTitle[Condensed]` ?

Comment: Not sure what is Condensed by neither:

 `@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
  MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_location);
  item.setTitleCondensed("TEST");
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }`

nor when using `item.setTitle("TEST");`

don't change title of any item in Menu. (I even removed icons for MenuItems to have only title displayed in Toolbar, but see [this screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dm19z1ge4wz5vhq/Przechwytywanie.JPG?dl=0) -  only initial titles areshown, no "TEST" there).

Comment: @pskink Just found out that when I moved `item.setTitle("TEST");` to onOptionsItemSelected then it worked.

When I tried to use setupBadge() on menu item from onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) I received an error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setCallback(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$Callback)' on a null object reference
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:112)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:94)`

Comment: It shows that error on this line inside BadgeDrawable class:        `super(new Drawable[]{dr});`

Comment: did you then try in `onCreateOptionsMenu` just inflate the menu and call `setupBadge` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`?

Comment: Yes, only then it WORKS! :)

Comment: great,  but this is very strange ;-)

Comment: It really is, actually I cannot explain why usage of same code in two different projects can vary as this. Anyway, @pskink - thank you for your time, really appreciate that.

Comment: if it works inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu` be careful with calling `setupBadge` as `onPrepareOptionsMenu` can be called **many many times**, unlike `onCreateOptionsMenu` which is called only once, so the best approach is using some boolean flag indicating if `setupBadge` was already called or not, or inside `setupBadge` check if `getIcon()` is instance of `BadgeDrawable`, in that case do nothing