# Changing the Nav Drawer icon in Action Bar to custom layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-custom-view

I have implemented a nav drawer in my app and works well.  There has been new requirement added to the project to display a notification count ON the nav drawer icon like below:

[image]

So my thought was to try and set a Relative Layout with an image view for hamburger icon and text view for the notification count.

I've looked around here (on SO) and online and I can't find anything that would help.  Is there anyway around this problem or has anyone done this before?  If I could do this without writing something custom that would be great as time is an issue.

I'm not looking for code, just pointing in the right direction.

Comment: what do you mean by *something custom*

Comment: They're called badges, if that helps your search. I know several questions like this have already been asked here.

Comment: @Mohit by something custom, I mean a custom component

Comment: @MikeM.  Thanks for your help.  I've come across a bit on badges for the app icon, I'm just wondering if it's possible for the nav drawer icon... have they been implemented in app?

Comment: I dont think there is any default component which allow you to pop up some other component with some value add a textview view will hardly increase you app complexity

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696486/actionbar-notification-count-badge-like-google-has) the first one that came up in my search. The two or three top-voted answers after the accepted answer are what you're looking for. It'll be easier to implement what you want if you use a `Toolbar`, though, instead of the `ActionBar`.

Comment: @MikeM.  Thanks for that, I found those too :) .However they don't do what I want, they just provide an additional menu item.  Thank you for your help

Comment: That's what I mean by using a `Toolbar` instead. You can set the Navigation icon on a `Toolbar` to whatever you want. Or, skip the built-in `View`s altogether, and just make a completely custom `Toolbar`.