# Show Notification count to android actionbar

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

GCM is implemented in my android application.Now i want to show the number of notification in home page action bar.How to get the notification count.please suggest me the appropriate code for this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696486/actionbar-notification-count-badge-like-google-has

Comment: This link specify how to set notification number to action bar .But my requirement is that how to get push notification count.

Comment: Have any idea about this topic?