# How to put a text at top right corner of menu icon on toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar

[Link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3u60.png)

I want to implement a bookmark feature and display the total bookmark numbers at top right of icon "Heart" on toolbar like the image above.

The text should be update immediately when new bookmark just added. (It is better if has a animation for this). 
I searched something on internet and SO but seem I can not find a good solution.

Please suggest me the way to do this or a good library can resolve my problems. Thanks.

Comment: the text above the heart button is a textview...and you must be adding new bookmark on some button click...get id of textview and update the text of that textview on button click with increment in last value.

Comment: @AnkushBist I got it but how to do that with a icon on menu toolbar ?

Comment: Take a look at this one - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25453979/2015538

Comment: @nbaroz It is great. Thanks