# How to show unread message count on app icon

Tags: android, android-layout, message

In my application I have some options, one is my messages, I need to show the unread count on that icon. How to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)

It has already disgussed.

https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Check this library out.

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25453979/5073666

Comment: Thanks for reply, i need to show in apps module icon not on app launcher icon. Is it possible to show?